# Can SVG stack lines of text without y coordinates like html table rows?

Tags: html, svg

So in HTML we can write rows of text easily, say with table rows or with successive p (paragraph) tags.

I want to write rows of text in SVG and was hoping not to have to wrestle with incremental y co-ordinates etc.

Also, I want to put border around the line of text, sometimes one row, other times multi-row.

As an overview I'm writing some code to XSLT transform some class definitions to a SVG implemented UML class diagram.  I will share code when complete (I'll drop a link in).  Here is a sample [UML Class diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm#Figure2ConceptualDiagram) that I am aiming at; you can see the class title sits in its own box, then the attributes re listed, then the metohds.

Comment: Ok, its a dupe @Kaido thanks